# Is any possible to correct this plpgsql (finding null(empty)columns in database) function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using PgAdmin1.16.I modified this function for finding null (empty) value columns in database, but 1) when i input(tab_name) table name some error occur.
2) This shows some not null value table also
 Is any possible to correct this function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_nullcolumns("tab_name" text,"num_input" int)
DECLARE
      null_columns   varchar;
      tab_name       ALIAS FOR $1;
      num_input      ALIAS FOR $2;
BEGIN
FOR    null_columns IN SELECT quote_ident(attname)
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'tab_name'::regclass 
AND    attnum >= num_input               
AND    NOT attisdropped           
AND    NOT attnotnull            
ORDER  BY attnum
LOOP
RAISE notice 'Tab_N:%', null_columns;
END LOOP;
RETURN null_columns;
END;
```

Comment: Read the doc about how to declare function parameters

Answer (score 0):

I change something in my function, it works good

```
WHERE  attrelid = 'tab_name'::regclass
```

I modify this

```
WHERE  attrelid = tab_name::regclass
```

and

```
Select get_nullcolumns('tab_name' ,num_input );     
Select get_nullcolumns('countyr_table' ,10 );
```

It works good for PgAdmin1.16

Answer (score 0):

Use this simpler SQL function instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_nullcolumns(tab_name regclass)
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$func$
SELECT attname
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = $1
AND    attnum >= 1
AND    NOT attisdropped           
AND    NOT attnotnull            
ORDER  BY attnum
$func  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.get_nullcolumns('mytable');
```

Your original had various syntax and logic errors.

The version of pgAdmin is unrelated, that's just the GUI.